# App icon not displaying in Google sign-in Page

Tags: ios

I am working on Google Sign-in integration to my app.On that i am not getting my app icon while Google asking to access Permission from user.Help me out to overcome this issue friends

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the solution by adding my imageURL in the following link

https://console.cloud.google.com/

Comment: Needs more explanation